# ObjC searching for @ in a string (iOS @ escape code)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm searching an NSString with an email to find the @ character.  Here's the code:

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"@"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) // do stuff
```

Here's the error I'm getting...

```
-[__NSCFNumber rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e51c550
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e51c550'
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're initializing 'string' - the variable for the message '[string rangeOfString:@"@"]'?

Comment: Your "string" is not an NSString, but rather an NSNumber.

Comment: (If you'd searched for "unrecognized selector sent to instance" you'd find this explained at least a thousand times.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `string` variable points to an instance of `NSNumber`, not an instance of `NSString`.  You are initializing it incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks rob, you're right.  I was storing both NSNumbers and NSStrings in an array, tried to use a simple for in loop without checking isKindOfClass or respondsToSelector.  Fail.